# How to query Specialized TreeList using GraphQL

Tags: graphql, tree-list

I have an item in sitecore which has a field with Specialized Treelist selection. I want to query this field using GraphQL query.

Query:

```
{
  item(path: "{98414240-69F7-4768-9B22-FE8EF17BE984}") {
    id
    path
    __typename
    
    field(name: "Navigation Links") {
      id
      name
      value
      __typename
      
      definition {
        type
        section
      }
    }
  }
}
```

GraphQL Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "item": {
      "id": "9841424069F747688B22FE8EF17BE844",
      "path": "/sitecore/content/AppName/Global/Configuration/Navigation/ItemName",
      "__typename": "LatestItems",
      "field": {
        "id": "C5533E0966FA4E00B392FAAC1371DA06",
        "name": "Navigation Links",
        "value": "{F533B0DB-085F-4FF5-BA35-D35E070D2210}|{2F23DDA3-EC80-47C8-87ZB-8F23598A08F3}|{EF9E7614-3D42-40A8-AFDD-47B0C62CE506}|{2F0E3536-0ABC-433A-8B4C-E1817E29298C}|{E8BCE000-08C9-4361-9D66-5FBA502C35F0}|{14A19584-E559-4449-9F42-6FD16FCC23E9}|{6511E9E0-DF97-478E-BBE8-2F1833B89BFE}|{3D5541DF-2891-4D88-ACD5-ECFB79A3C5A5}|{D3AD6307-F7E0-4951-3232-6A44E8C99ABF}|{898C8997-16C2-4B0E-B87F-49E09DCCB553}",
        "__typename": "TextField",
        "definition": {
          "type": "Specialized Treelist",
          "section": "Content"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want the pipe separated values to show the details of item e.g title, displayName, fields etc.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by adding the mapping for Specialized TreeList in the graphql content config.

**Config Path:**
inetpub\wwwroot\sitename\Website\App_Config\Sitecore\Services.GraphQL\Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.config

**Append below line:**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore>
        <api>
            <GraphQL>
                <!-- the defaults section contains config templates that can be reused elsewhere using 'ref' -->
                <defaults>
                    <content>
                        <fieldTypeMappings>
                            <standardTypeMapping type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.TemplateGeneration.FieldTypeToGraphQLTypeMapper, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content">
                                <typeMapping hint="raw:AddTypeMapping">

                                    <map field="Specialized Treelist" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.TemplateGeneration.FieldMapping.MultilistFieldTypeFactory, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content" />

                                </typeMapping>
                            </standardTypeMapping>
                        </fieldTypeMappings>
                    </content>
                </defaults>
            </GraphQL>
        </api>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get items from the list by using the targetItems. by using a inline fragment you can cast the field to a List. The query looks like somethings like this:

```
 {
  item(path: "{98414240-69F7-4768-9B22-FE8EF17BE984}") {
    id
    path
    __typename
    
    field(name: "Navigation Links") {
      id
      name
      value
      ...NavLinks
      __typename
      
      definition {
        type
        section
      }
    }
  }
  
  fragment NavLinks on MultilistField {
    navlink: targetItems {
     name
     id
     field(name: "title") {
      mytitle: value
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for the suggestion. The problem is that "Navigation Links" type is shown as TextField by GraphQL in the response I mentioned in the question. Thats why the above NavLinks fragment does not work. It does not have any impact on the response.

Comment: I feel that GraphQL is not able to understand the "Specialized Treelist" type hence it converts it into TextField. Thoughts?

Comment: yep that make sense, custom field, looks like not able to cast